# Protect record view based on criteria for sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-views

I have a list and I need to protect who can view specific records based on list values. My company have sub-departments. For example the department is **Office-Management** and under this there are ***Office-HR***, ***Office-IT*** etc. I have created a list that contain all members per Office-Management. How can I set a filtering in a custom View that will present records only those who I am member. For example I am in the sub-department **Office-IT** and I must see only the records that have for sub-department **Office-IT**

Answer (score 0):

Is the Office-HR a group name?

If yes, out of the box approach will be to add more views on the page with different set of columns and set the audience targeting property of the web part to the particular user group.

When you edit the list view web part, in "Advanced" tab you will get "Target Audiences" option.